# Binding an argument as this, with a new constructor?

Tags: javascript, call, bind

I am trying to bind an argument for `this` to a function named `Sequence` the binding works, problem is more than one `Sequence` overwrites each other, so I have to use `new` here's the issue...

```
//js code
function init(cmd) {
    cmd.exec.call(e,Sequence.bind(cmd));
}
```

**Example**

```
init({
    exec:function(seq){
        seq("a",function(){
            console.log(this);// returns init object itself
        });
    }
});
```

Works great but when I do

```
//init for js above
...,function(seq) {
    seq("a",function(){
        console.log ("hello");
    },document.getElementById("google"));
});
...,function(seq) {
    seq("d",function(){
        console.log("goodbye");
    });
});
```

The second sequence is ran `goodbye`. never the first because it is being written over.

**Sequence function**

```
function Sequence(key, fn, location) {
    if (!location) location = document;
    var self = this; //object that is bound to Sequence
    location.addEventListener("keydown", function sequenceMode(e) {
      if(self.waiting)
      {
        if (keyCodes.literal[key.toUpperCase()] === e.which) {
          fn.call(self,e);
          self.waiting = false;
          this.removeEventListener("keydown", sequenceMode);
        }
      } else location.removeEventListener("keydown", sequenceMode);
    });
}
```

So my issue here is how do I `A` bind the this property to be the object calling `Sequence` or `B` how do I create a new instance of `Sequence` and still allow the user to define inside the function?

```
cmd.call(e,new Sequence().bind(cmd)); //can not call bind from Constructor
```

So basically I need to have the user still be able to define the arguments themselves for `Sequence` and `this` be bound to the object calling it. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

http://jsbin.com/dulesejame

Not getting the same results so I'm overlooking my code now,
So I've edited the bin with my actual JavaScript. It's doing it now.

Open the developer panel to read console. Press `ctrl+a` then b, then press `ctrl+b` press a, doesn't show any so press b and it's running `ctrl+a` seq function.

Comment: Post some fiddle, if you can! I couldn't get your problem exactly...

Comment: Yeah I always have a problem giving my issues. I'll get a fiddle going

Comment: added the bin with my actual JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One main issue I can tell you is using the same `default` object, by which your `commands.cmd[combinator]` will point to the same object which came last.

Make a copy of `default` before assigning

```
var def = Object.create(defaults);
for(var option in options)
{
  if(option !== "executed" && option !== "called")
  {
    def[option] = options[option];
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright I'll give that a whirl. I forgot about that, I just got back into Javascript and thought making a variable would create a new instance basically like pass by reference,etc.

Comment: Accepted your answer because you lead me to the error, though I didn't use this exactly I created a new Object literal instead. Thanks @code-jaff

Answer (score 0):

After realizing what I did wrong thank's to code-jaff which I'll accept his answer since he did give me the way to it. Except instead of using `Object.create` I just created a new Object literal.

```
var def = {};
for(var option in defaults)
{
  if(options.hasOwnProperty(option) && option !== "executed" && option !== "called" && option !== "waiting")
  {
    def[option] = options[option];
  } else {
    def[option] = defaults[option];
  }
}
```